# Does this Limit Make Sense?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Do the following limits make sense?
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\delta\to 0}\sup\{f(x):x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)\}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\delta\to 0}\inf\{f(x):x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)\}.
\end{align*}
I recognize if one of these expressions makes sense, then so does the other. However, I'm uncertain of whether they are actually valid.

Comment: That was a mistake, meant $\inf$

Comment: OK, they make sense if $f$ is real function defined in a neighbourhood of $c$.

Comment: Yes and that the values of $f$ are real numbers

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help

Comment: See those slight different definitions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Real-valued_functions

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for. These definitions seem to arise naturally in analysis

Comment: Yes, but usually the point $c$ is omitted:$\lim_{\delta\to 0}\sup\{f(x):x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)\setminus\{c\}\}$

Comment: That makes sense; when dealing with limits, the behaviour of the function near $a$ seems to be more important than the value exactly at $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are even always guaranteed to exist if you allow for infinity as value and limit. The $\sup$ of an empty set is $-\infty$ so $f$ doesn't even have to be defined in a neighborhood of $c$.

They even have their own name "limes inferior" and "limes superior" (if you omit the $c$):

$$\limsup_{\delta\to0} f(c+\delta) = \lim_{\delta\to0}\sup\{f(x): c-\delta<x<c+\delta\land x\ne c\}$$
$$\liminf_{\delta\to0} f(c+\delta) = \lim_{\delta\to0}\inf\{f(x): c-\delta<x<c+\delta\land x\ne c\}$$

Comment: Is the existence of these limits a consequence of the well-ordered property of the reals?

Comment: No, it's because of the least-upper-bound property (these are not guaranteed to exist within $\mathbb Q$ for example). The RHS can be rewritten as $\inf\sup$ and $\sup\inf$ respectively and these are guaranteed to exist if the set is non-empty and bounded (or you accept infinities).

Comment: Okay, one more question: do all the limit theorems still apply? e.g. limit of a sum is the sum of the limits, the squeeze theorem, etc?